# Pandas - Expand Name & Value Columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm not sure what the technical name of the desired operation is, but I have data in the following format where my field names are a column and the corresponding values are a column. Currently, I filtered a new df to each field name and then concat all three back together which is clunky and not ideal (I'm sure there is a better way).

```
dummy_data = {
'Field_Names': ['Field_1','Field_2','Field_3','Field_1','Field_2','Field_3'],
'Field_Values': ['Bob','John','Kyle','Eric','Pat','Rana']
}
dummy_df = pd.DataFrame(dummy_data)
```

I would like the field names to be their own columns. Desired output is below:

```
details = {'Field_1': ['Bob', 'Eric'],
           'Field_2': ['John', 'Pat'],
           'Field_3': ['Kyle', 'Rana']}

desired_output = pd.DataFrame(details)

print(desired_output)
```

There is likely a pandas method for this but again, I'm not sure what the technical name is for the operation I'm looking to perform. I am using Python 3.7+ in Jupyter on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to do a `.groupby()` on the field names and collect the field values in a list:

```
g = dummy_df.groupby('Field_Names')['Field_Values'].apply(list)
desired_output = pd.DataFrame({i:g.loc[i] for i in g.index.to_list()}
```

Update: My mistake that was only part of the solution. I've updated the code above. My output now:

```
    Field_1 Field_2 Field_3
0   Bob    John Kyle
1   Eric    Pat Rana
```

Comment: your output does not match OP's expected output

Comment: Oh you're right. One more step to transpose and explode. I'll update my answer. Thanks!